# Azure Function & PowerBI

Tags: azure, powerbi

I have 6 HTTP Triggered Azure Functions written in .NET and all the functions are running fine.

I was wondering if these Function's URL could be invoked ONLY through Power BI and not in any browser.

Is this even feasible?  .. I was reading about Managed Identity

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview
```

Wanted some guidance and some sort of confirmation before I spend time into it .. Is this even feasible after all .. azure function is a URL.

Comment: maybe if you use a Power App visual, that has a button that hits the url